# How do I extract the content of quoted strings of a specific property path from an output?

Tags: sed, grep, terminal, macos, json

I have an output from a web server response in JSON which looks like this:

```
{"status":"OK","result":{"string":{"variable":0},"string2":[{"id":"03489579q2074hvissdiuh:023427598042ztuoihsgasflbkc6dc7e000af669d6c94857d1a28f8cb338a9691c80eb8857c750c8ead70f29a","string3":"string4","latitude":"01.XXXXXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXXXX"},]}}
```

and is saved as `response.txt`. it repeats for many iterations, so after `"02.XXXXXXX"}` follows an `","`

my expected output is only the contents of `"id"`:

```
03489579q2074hvidssiuh:023427598042ztuoihsgasflbkc6dc7e000af669d6c94857d1a28f8cb338a9691c80eb8857c750c8ead70f29a
```

with a new line after each id.

I tried methods such as

```
grep -o '".*"' somefile | tr -d '",{}[]'

awk -F- '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if ($i ~ "^ram.+") { sub("^ram","",$i); print $i} }
    }' response.txt
id

sed 's/.*id\(\w\+\).*/\1/' response.txt

sed 's/.*id..\(.*\)..300.*/\1/' -d '",{}[]' response.txt

sed 's/^.* id (\([0-9\.%]*\).*$/\1/' response.txt
```

but it will either return me everything back, only the first iteration with some special characters still present or an error since awk isn't available in the macOS terminal by default.

Thank you

Edit: here is an output with more iterations

```
{"status":"OK","result":{"string1":{"veriable":0},"string2":[{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX","tier":"normal","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"},{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX","tier":"normal","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"},{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX,"tier":"special","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"},{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX","tier":"normal","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"}]}}
```

Comment: Is the missing quote at column 250 of your added input with more iterations actually there or did you make a mistake?

Comment: I think that might’ve been an error on my side, as you can see in the comments under your answer it throws me another error now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jq`:

```bsh
jq -r '.result.string2[].id' response.txt
```

Input:

```json
{
  "status": "OK",
  "result": {
    "string1": {
      "veriable": 0
    },
    "string2": [
      {
        "id": "XXXXX:XXXXX",
        "tier": "normal",
        "latitude": "01.XXXXX",
        "longitude": "02.XXXXX"
      },
      {
        "id": "XXXXX:XXXXX",
        "tier": "normal",
        "latitude": "01.XXXXX",
        "longitude": "02.XXXXX"
      },
      {
        "id": "XXXXX:XXXXX",
        "tier": "special",
        "latitude": "01.XXXXX",
        "longitude": "02.XXXXX"
      },
      {
        "id": "XXXXX:XXXXX",
        "tier": "normal",
        "latitude": "01.XXXXX",
        "longitude": "02.XXXXX"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
XXXXX:XXXXX
XXXXX:XXXXX
XXXXX:XXXXX
XXXXX:XXXXX
```

Comment: Thank you! but I am getting an error: `jq: error (at response.txt:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

Comment: This works with your input string when you remove the `,` to make it valid. Please edit your question and add some more input lines. Maybe copy-paste nicely formatted with `jq < response.txt`

Comment: `+zsh: no matches found: .string2[].id`

Comment: @Claire you sanitized your input and indeed `,` doesn't make a valid json.

Comment: `zsh` error seems to me like you did not use proper quotes and `zsh` trying to evaluate it...

Comment: The output txt is exactly like i'm receiving it in raw from the web server, with `,`. I believe your command doesn't consider that I have many iterations over and over, so the output has these  `,` because it repeats, at least 20 times, I just gave you only one to make it shorter.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "many iterations". Can you give us at least 2 iterations, so we know what you mean? Please edit your question.

Comment: No problem, I edited my question!

Comment: This new version **is** valid `json` (after adding a missing quote at column 250) and works fine with the first command.

Comment: Here is my current process from the beginning. I paste the output as output.json or output.txt, I run the script and get `jq: error (at response.json:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)`. So i remove every `,` in my code editor with find and replace. After that, I now get `parse error: Expected separator between values at line 1, column 22` :(

Comment: Nevermind, this works. I forgot that string2 is not the actual string name but a placeholder... so sorry.