# Use conditional formatting in jq

Tags: macos, json, jq

This is a follow up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697495/how-do-i-extract-the-content-of-quoted-strings-of-a-specific-property-path-from?noredirect=1#comment1317962_697495) asked by me a few days ago.

Say I have this output from a webserver

```
{"status":"OK","result":{"string1":{"variable":0},"string2":[{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX","tier":"normal","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"},{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX","tier":"normal","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"},{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX,"tier":"special","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"},{"id":"XXXXX:XXXXX","tier":"normal","latitude":"01.XXXXX","longitude":"02.XXXXX"}]}}
```

saved as `response.json` and only want "`id`" as output. I achieve this using `jq -r '.result.string2[].id' response.json`.

Now my question is, how do I set a condition so jq will only output me the "`id`"s if `tier:"special"`?

Thanks!

Here are some options I tried but only got errors:

```
jq -r ' |.result.string2[].id.tier select(== "special") | .id ' responses.json

jq -r '.result.string2[].id | select( has("tier.special") )' responses.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
jq -r '.result.string2[] | select(.tier == "special").id' responses.json
```

or, without the shortcut of applying `.id` directly on `select()`:

```bsh
jq -r '.result.string2[] | select(.tier == "special") | .id' responses.json
```

Expand the `string2` array, pick out the entry or entries that have the correct value for `tier` with `select()`, and then pick out the `id` of these.

To arrive at this, you could build up the expression bit by bit and run it several times on a sample document.  Start with `.result` to see what that returns, then `.result.string2`, etc.  This way, you would notice right away that you attempt that places a `|` first in the expression would not work, and that `.result.string2[].id` results in a list that does not contain `tier` (so you can't use `select()` on it to filter on `tier`).

You would also notice that the sample document that you show in the question lacks a double quote after one of its values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanation :)