# Use conditional formatting in jq - PowerShell

Tags: windows, json, jq, powershell

This is a follow up question from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697830/use-conditional-formatting-in-jq/697831#697831?newreg=a7acab0529c84b0db21711d5df19eb85) that got contributed by another person. I have following output from a webserver:

```
{
    "status":"OK",
    "result":{
        "string1":{
            "variable":0
        },
        "string2":[
            {
                "id":"XXXXX:XXXXX",
                "tier":"normal",
                "latitude":"01.XXXXX",
                "longitude":"02.XXXXX"
            },
            {
                "id":"XXXXX:XXXXX",
                "tier":"normal",
                "latitude":"01.XXXXX",
                "longitude":"02.XXXXX"
            },
            {
                "id":"XXXXX:XXXXX",
                "tier":"special",
                "latitude":"01.XXXXX",
                "longitude":"02.XXXXX"
            },
            {
                "id":"XXXXX:XXXXX",
                "tier":"normal",
                "latitude":"01.XXXXX",
                "longitude":"02.XXXXX"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i'm extracting the ids with  `jq -r '.result.string2[].id' responses.json` right now and safing them as a `responses.json` file; this works perfectly fine.

However, my question is, how do i set the condition so jq will only output me the `id`'s if `tier: "special"`? I tried to solve it with the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697830/use-conditional-formatting-in-jq/697831#697831?newreg=a7acab0529c84b0db21711d5df19eb85) in this thread, alias these two:

```
jq -r '.result.string2[] | select(.tier == "special") | .id'responses.json

jq -r '.result.string2[] | select(.tier == "special") | .id' responses.json
```

This doesn't seem to work in my Windows-PowerShell.
It gives me the following error message:

```
 jq: error: special/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.result.string2[] | select(.tier == special) | .id jq: 1 compile error
```

Thanks for answering!

Comment: @steeldriver The `special` in the question _appears_ quoted. I don't know Powershell at all. Does it do strange things to quoted strings?

Comment: I'll eat a little crow here.  I installed jq on my windows machine and I get the same error even with valid json.  I sort of apologize but not really.  You came here and copied invalid input, the wrong command, and the wrong error from another question.  And then told us just not to worry about it and to trust you.  That is not how it works.

Comment: @jesse_b So, a Powershell issue then.

Comment: @Kusalananda: seems like it.  I'm trying to get it to work but I have no idea why it's behaving this way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is not related to unix or linux.

Comment: PowerShell already has built-in json parsing with cmdlets like `ConvertFrom-Json`, `ConvertTo-Json`... why don't just use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes likely because powershell does not preserve them within single quotes like a POSIX shell does.

```
jq -r '.result.string2[] | select(.tier == \"special\") | .id'
```

Comment: On Windows commands have to parse their own command lines, it's **jq taking out the double quotes from its own command line** while it tries to interpret it (cf. errors from `jq -n '"abc"'` and `jq -n "'abc'"`). Powershell interprets the single quotes and gives jq a single string with the double quotes intact, which is why backslash-escape works rather than Powershell's backtick-escaping - jq understands the backslashes to escape the quotes.

Comment: PowerShelll does preserve `""` inside `''`. The OP just used the wrong tool. Native PowerShell `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` are much better and are portable to all PowerShell platforms